# Display memo fields in VFP

Tags: database, select, visual-foxpro, memo

How to display the content of memo fields with select command?
If I have a table (vendors) with the following fields: id_vendor C(10),address M and I want to display all the content with "select * from vendors" I receive only the type of field but not the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are viewing the results in a browse window (which is what executing the SQL will show), then ctrl+pgdown in the field (where it is showing "Memo") will display the entire contents in a new window.

The SQL did retrieve the entire contents, which can be confirmed by in the command windows entering

? [fieldname]

And you will see the contents that way also.

Answer (score 2):

Which language are you using or what it your output audience... if within VFP, use an EDIT field to allow for multiple row content to be shown.  In a simple "text box" field, it will only show "memo" as you indicate.  Otherwise, as Swordblaster indicated ctrl+pgdown or even double-clicking SHOULD open it, but that would throw up an uncontrolled "window" for you vs a controlled "edit box" control which you can specifically place in your window as needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Double click** `Memo` and the contents are displayed in a new window.

[image: vfp grid screenshot]

[image: vfp memo contents screenshot]